# Compare $L_2$ norm of Fourier series of $ f$ and $ f'$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a periodic continuous function on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f'$ continuous.
Let the Fourier series of $f$ be ${a_o\over 2} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n\cos nx  + b_n \sin nx).$
Is it true that $$||f-{a_0\over2}||^2 \leq ||f'||$$ , where ||.|| is the $L_2$ norm?
I have tried some functions and this seems to hold, but I don't know how to prove it.
My guess is to compare the Fourier series of $f$ and $f'$.
Let $s_n$ be the n-th partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$, then in $L_2$ $s_n$ converges to $f$. Let $\sum$ be the infinite summation part of the Fourier series ($s_n-{a_0\over2}$) then
$$||f-{a_0\over2}|| \leq ||f-s_n||+||\sum||$$
but since $||f-s_n||$ can be made as small as we want,
$$||f-{a_0\over2}|| \leq ||\sum||$$.

If I can compare $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n\cos nx  + b_n \sin nx)$ and $f'$I can get somewhere....

Comment: What are your approaches?

Comment: What happens for $f (x)=\sin(x/2)$?

Comment: @ Friedrich Philipp, I added my approach so far.
@JeanMarie, I don't get what you're hinting at

Comment: @Niebla ; $\{\sin(nx)\}_{n \ge 1} \cup \{\cos(nx)\}_{n \ge 0}$ is an orthogonal family of elements of $L^2([0,2\pi])$, this means that $\|\sum_n (a_n \cos(nx)+b_n \sin(nx))\|^2 = \sum_n (|a_n|^2 \ \|\cos(nx)\|^2 +|b_n|^2 \ \|\sin(nx)\|^2 )$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see where that leads. I mean, if I can compare term by term the Fourier coefficients of $f$ and $f'$ then I'm done, but I don't see how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it!
So I followed user1952009's suggestion.
Consider the Fourier series of f':
$$ {A_o\over 2} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty(A_n\cos nx  + B_n \sin nx)$$
Now, $A_o=\int_0^{2\pi}f'd{x}=f(2\pi)-f(0)=0  $ by periodicity of $f$
$A_n=\int_0^{2\pi}f'\cos{(nx)} dx$ integrating by part, this can be written in terms of f and you find $A_n=-nb_n$. Similarly $B_n=na_n$.
$f'$ is Riemann integrable, so its Fourier series converges to $f'$ in $L_2$ norm.
Also, $||\sin nx||=||\cos nx||$. Clearly $|a_n|\leq |na_n|$.
Therefore
$$||f-{a_n \over 2}||^2=||\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n\cos nx  + b_n \sin nx)||^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(|a_n|^2||\cos nx||^2  + |b_n|^2 ||\sin nx||^2) \leq $$
$$\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty(|na_n|^2||\sin nx||^2  + |nb_n|^2 ||\cos nx||^2= ||f'||^2$$

And the desired inequality follows.
Let me know if you think that this works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your proof works, but it's probably overkill (for my taste at least). Once you realise that $\frac{a_0}{2}$ is just the mean value of $f$, you will see that your claimed inequality is nothing but the [Poincaré(-Wirtinger)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality#The_Poincar.C3.A9-Wirtinger_inequality) inequality, so you are done.